# Fine-grained Access Control Object Storage Softlayer

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have a softlayer account and wanted to add additional user and grant him read-only access to the Object Storage to a specific container. I could not do this on the portal. 
Can anyone let me know if there is any api to grant such level of access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently that is not possible in softlayer, you only can grant access or deny access if you grant access the user will be able to create,read and delete objects.